# How to append lines that match two patterns to the previous line in a file?

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a csv file where what's supposed to be a single line, is split across several. I need help to find a way to join the lines that are split. Also, the number of fields (separated by ,) is not fixed.

A correct line has the following pattern:

X,X,X,"()**",Y,H** where X can be any number of fields. However, the bold part (end of the string) is fixed. Y and H are both one word.

The issue is that this line can appear as (or any variant of this):

X,X,

X, "()"

,Y,H

What I need is a way (awk, sed) of appending the lines that don't have 24 or more commas and do not end with ",Y,H, to the previous line.

Please bear in mind that it's a large file, although I have 256 GB of RAM.

**Example**

- Correct lines

a, b, c, "()", h, k

a, b, c, d, "()", h, k

- Same lines in the file

First line

a, b, c,

"()", h, k

Second line

a, b, c, d, "()"

, h

, k

So far I've tried this (not working):

**awk '/"[:space:]*,[:space:]*[:alpha:]+[:space:]*,[:space:]*[:alpha:]+$/{print}' check.csv**

to try to find the lines ending with ", X, Y where X and Y are words.

Also, as the minimum number of correct fields is 24, I've used:

**awk 'NF<24{print}' check.csv**

to filter out lines with less than 24 fields.

My idea is to detect lines that match both regular expressions and append them to the previous line.

Thank you!

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help . Please put code and file contents inside "code and preformated text" style.

Comment: define "large file". 500MB isn't a large file in awk's eyes.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/"()", *[^,]\+, *[^,]\+$/b;:a;N;s/\n//;/"()", *[^,]\+, *[^,]\+$/!ba;P;D' file
```

Do not process a correct line, just bail out.

Otherwise append the next line, remove the introduced newline and try and match again.

Repeat until a match, then print/delete the first line and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

`perl -lanF, -e 'push @L, grep length, @F; if ($L[-3] eq q/"()"/) { print join ",", @L; @L=() }' file`

- use `-l -n -e` to loop over input lines w/o printing, append linebreaks to output
- use `-a -F,` to create `@F` array by splitting input on commas
- `push @L, grep length, @F` push nonempty fields onto `@L`
- `if ($L[-3] eq q/"()"/)` - if the 3rd to last accumulated field is the magic marker:

  - `print join ",", @L` print all of `@L` joined with commas
  - `@L=()` reset `@L`